# What could happen if letters were banned in written form?

Tags: communication, hardcopy

I am looking for all kinds of problems that would result from the global ban on alphabet letters (characters) in written form, this includes diacritics and other foreign characters. A global ban, that is when all the governments magically decide to ban them at once, with immediate effect. Imagine anything that contains letters - documents, books, letter stickers, posters, computers that output such data - what could be the consequences?

Comment: Everyone would learn Chinese.

Comment: Be more specific. Banned by whom? What happens if you write a letter - will you be fined or what? And what are "letters" exactly (people still can use cipher, can't they).

Comment: The law being ignored/collapse of civilisation/revolution/all of the above

Comment: [Fahrenheit 451](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fahrenheit_451)

Comment: As enkryptor suggested, please [edit] your question. And replace 'letters' with 'characters'. [This is also a letter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_%28message%29)

Comment: China did actually try to puill this off.  The line between an abstract symbol and a character is very small.  One year, they banned the unicode symbol for a candle nationally, because it was being used as a character to communicate rememberence of Tiananmen square.  When they banned it, people picked another symbol, and turned it into a character to communicate the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you saying banned as in "made illegal" or banned as in "totally expunged and forgotten"? if the first one, you could do something like fahrenheit 451, where writing is limited to the bare necessity; if the second, it would be difficult to imagine a civilization at our current level of development surviving the switch. you could solve this by making the society in which this takes place much more or less technologically advanced than ours. a high-tech species could either record everything as video or audio recordings, and maybe use some kind of speech-based programming language. a species without any computers would have a harder time; assuming that pictographs are also out of the question, they would have to rely on oral history and sending messengers to take the place of books and letters. This is probably more plausible, and would also work for a more advanced civilization. alternatively, you could have them just revert back to a primitive level, but that would remove the ability of any government or group to enforce the ban on characters.